# Is a continuously differentiable function convex if all its partial second derivatives are non-negative?

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis

I'm having trouble understanding [the relevant Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function) which begins with a convex set $X$ and then uses functions of single variables for succeeding examples; the [MathWorld article](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConvexFunction.html) seems to be concerned only with functions of a single variable.

I would specifically enjoy seeing a proof that is relatively easy to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wait, I've got it.

> More generally, a continuous, twice differentiable function of several variables is convex on a convex set if and only if its Hessian matrix is positive semidefinite on the interior of the convex set.

From the same Wikipedia article above. Neither proven nor sourced directly, though.

Comment: A proof is easy if you realize that (1) convexity can be tested by looking at the restrictions to lines; (2) the derivative of the restriction of $f$ to line with direction vector $v$ can be expressed in terms of the Hessian $H$ as $v^THv$.

Comment: Nice! I'll try that later.

Answer (score 3):

No.  For example, all of the partial second derivatives of the function $f(x,y) = xy$ are everywhere non-negative, but this function is not convex.